# Does ExifInterface.TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE really measure shutter speed? If so, how to convert it to a more standard format?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-exifinterface

I'm trying to get camera shutter speed when a photo is taken with Android camera. Using this instruction in an image the app creates that contains the taken photo.

double vel = exif.getAttributeDouble(ExifInterface.TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE, 0);

This gives some values that change according to the level of luminosity, for example right now if I allow natural light to go through my window fully it offers the value 6.906 and if I don't allow it as much as possible it is 3.882.

But on the other hand I'm using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.footej.camera2&hl=en_US&gl=US) to check correctness of the values and for these same cases it offers the values 1/120 and 1/12, which seem to be on a standard format to represent shutter speed as seen [here](https://wp-modula.com/shutter-speed-photography/#:%7E:text=Common%20shutter%20speed%20values%20The%20common%20shutter%20speeds,faster%20shutter%20speed%20than%201%2F8th%20of%20a%20second.).

I can't grasp if ExifInterface.TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE is measuring shutter speed correctly, but in other scale which I don't know how to convert or if it's doing that in a wrong way and using it wouldn't help.

Could anyone tell me how to convert to the 1/x format from the value it gives or tell me if it's measuring any other thing?

Comment: Which `Exifinterface` are you using [androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE) or [android.media.ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, it's android.media.ExifInterface.

Comment: The more standard forms like 1/125 and 1/12 are not really speeds to begin with. They are times/durations expressed in seconds.

Comment: @blackapps, you are right, but for some reason they usually call that "shutter speed".

Comment: FYI: [Shutter Speed from the Exif ShutterSpeedValue](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/108817/67934)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

The [TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE) unit is the APEX value.

Not sure about about this source but this is the only answer I found about the APEX value calculation: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/54376235

> ShutterSpeed=-log2(ExposureTime).

And it matches your values:

```
-log2(1/120) = 6.907
-log2(1/12) = 3.585
```

Anyway, if your are looking for the exposure time value in second, you can directly read the [TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME) instead.